# Making Ninject Interceptor's Intercept method an async method

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, ninject-interception

I'm using Ninject Interceptor in order do some tasks before and after the actual method gets called but I need these operations to be asynchronous. I have take a look at the following article [making-ninject-interceptors-work-with-async-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630548/making-ninject-interceptors-work-with-async-methods) and implement  that async part, but now I'm missing one last piece and that is waiting / non-blocking wait for task to complete in Intercept method.

- I can't use wait because I want this to be asynchronous non-blocking operation

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Intercepts the specified invocation.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="invocation">The invocation to intercept.</param>
  public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
      Task<bool> resultTask = InterceptAsync(invocation);
      if (resultTask.Exception != null)
          throw new Exception("Exception.", resultTask.Exception.InnerException);
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Intercepts the specified invocation.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="invocation">The invocation to intercept.</param>
  protected async Task<bool> InterceptAsync(IMyInvocation invocation)
  {
      await BeforeInvokeAsync(invocation);
      if (!invocation.Cancel)
      {
          invocation.Proceed();
          await AfterInvokeAsync(invocation);
      }
      return true;
   }
  ```
- I have even tried to put the async on this method and I still have problems, probably with the fact this is a void method

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Intercepts the specified invocation.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="invocation">The invocation to intercept.</param>
  public async void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
  {
      Task<bool> resultTask = InterceptAsync(invocation);
      await resultTask;
      if (resultTask.Exception != null)
          throw new Exception("Exception.", resultTask.Exception.InnerException);
  }
  ```

Is there a way to make this real async all the way method ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure NInject's current design just doesn't allow for asynchronous pre-execution, because `Proceed` *must* be called synchronously. I recommend you raise this issue with NInject support.

Comment: To clarify, I mean `Proceed` must be called synchronously from `Intercept`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying, _Proceed must be called synchronously from Intercept_ do you mean this has to be called synchronously because Intercept is not designed (and the rest of interception) asynchronously ? BTW I have raised the question on Ninject Interception GitHub issues section yesterday so we will see what happens.

Comment: Right. If you `await` before you call `Proceed`, then your method actually returns, and when you return, Intercept assumes that the call is done (pulls out `ReturnValue` etc). When your method resumes later, it will try to call `Proceed` long after Intercept has completed that call. So it can't work with the current design; Intercept would have to change to have a more WebAPI-like architecture to fully support asynchronous interception.

Comment: Yup I thought so, thanks for insights.

Comment: For Googlers, the GitHub issue is [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception/issues/17).

Comment: One question regarding the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630548/making-ninject-interceptors-work-with-async-methods) I'm trying to wait synchronously for _BeforeInvokeAsync_ & _AfterInvokeAsync_ without getting a deadlock, any ideas how to achieve that ?

Comment: It's not possible in the general case. You can play tricks with `Task.Run` or whatnot, but there's no general solution short of rewriting NInject Intercept.

Comment: Yes, I have been playing with Task.Run, Wait etc. I'll post a dirty fix if I find it. One other side note is that changing Ninject Intercept isn't enough as you need to change the dependent proxy library _LinFu_ or _Castle.Core DynamicProxy_.

Answer (score 2):

I have been forced to hack my way out of this issue and I have changed few bits of code inside **Ninject.Extensions.Interception** to allow **async/await**.

I have just started testing the code and so far it seems that **awaiting** before *Proceed* is called is working. I'm not 100% sure that everything is working as expected because I need more time to play with this, so feel free to check out the implementation and get back to me if you find bugs or have suggestions.

https://github.com/khorvat/ninject.extensions.interception

**IMPORTANT** - this solution works only with LinFu DynamicProxy as LinFu generates proxy classes in way that can be used to allow asynchronous waiting.

*Note: Again this solution is a "hack" and not the full asynchronous interception implementation.*

Regards